# Can a human eat alien food for the tastiness? And vice versa

Tags: science-based, xenobiology, food

Would it be plausible for a human to eat an alien's food (and vice versa) not because said being needs nutrition or such but purely to enjoy alien cuisine. Assuming the species is fairly compatible; they both are carbon based, have DNA like structures, etc. . . Could a human (or alien) try some alien foods and, disregarding whether or not they enjoy it, experience it. What problems might arise and how would they be circumvented?

(As a footnote I am aware this pretty unlikely the questions more to ask, can I plausibly present this in a piece of fiction with minimum hand waving.)

Comment: Very much opinion based?

Comment: Hi TheImperial, I agree with Jefferey's comment here that this is a highly subjective, entirely opinion-based question. Can I recommend you check out our [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) so we can help you get this question better within the scope of the site? I've voted to place your question on-hold until it's less ambiguous.

Comment: Ehh. Yeah the way I Presented it I can see that. It's supposed to be a question about how plausible it would be to have aliens trying some of each others food. Based in science. So like, how probleble would it be for an alien to experience sweetness from a sugary drink or the spiciness of pepper. and the problems that might occur and how you could circumvent said problems. feel free to edit if you think it could be clearer and ask if I'm still not clear on my original intent!

Comment: @TheImperial Estimating probabilities for an alien species' taste buds is... tricky, at best. In the end, the question will depend exclusively on how similar those aliens are to humans, and how much of our biology they share. If they've got GPCRs, then they may be able to detect sweetness or savoriness, but whether they *enjoy* that sensation is very vague. Humans themselves can't even agree on whether spiciness is pleasant or torturous.

Comment: @TheImperial Regarding taste buds of even quite similar and relatively closely related species - dogs don't taste sugar and are quite happy, given a chance to eat their own feces which is revolting to us. Whilst generally true that we're attracted to stuff that's nutritious - [durian fruit](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/durian-fruit) is revolting to most people, but nutritious. Personally, I'd figure out what story I was trying to tell and adapt the facts to fit. [The sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) is a good start.

Comment: Are aliens going to eat human food? They will if you write them to, they won't if you don't. It's *impossible* to say what aliens will or will not eat - we have not met any. However, will humans eat *alien food* is easier to answer - *most likely* they would. There are plants that use their own leaves and fruits to *contaminate the ground around*, to prevent competition. And yet people consume this substance *willingly*. It's called caffeine. Another plant causes anything that eats it to feel as if it's burning to ward them off. But hot peppers are very widely eaten, too. People try anything.

Answer (score 3):

Our tastebuds are optimized to find tasty foods that give us required nutrients.  Modernly, it is easy to overeat some nutrients, like fats and sugars, but those still provide dense calories (meaning lots for a relatively small amount of food).  This habit of finding certain foods tasty encourages us to seek out those foods.  Which when such foods were rare or difficult to get, served to provide an incentive.

I mention this because the first problem that I see here is that it is more likely that foods will be tasty and full of calories or not tasty and empty of calories.  Empty of calories and tasty is an unlikely (but not impossible; consider aspartame for an example) combination.  Full of calories but bad tasting is more likely.

If the alien has a distinct biology from ours, it seems unlikely that we could eat their food at all.  Most of their food would probably not only taste bad but be poisonous.

All that said, it is not ridiculous or impossible for a single foodstuff to happen to be nonnutritious, tasty, and not poisonous.  For example, honey is almost pure sugar.  So unless sugar itself is poisonous to the alien, there is a good chance it would be safe for the alien to consume.  If the alien doesn't metabolize sugar, it might pass through.

Since we don't know of any distinct biologies, we don't really have any way of saying how common this is.  So we can't say that it can't happen.  Nor can we prove that it can.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, but in a best case scenario, yes.

Assuming alien food is not toxic in any way and does not clog human digestive system, it will just pass through it, acting as dietary fiber. But of course there is a definite potential for this food to act harmfully, for example as a low intensity carcinogen, so I personally would not recommend eating something that is completely alien.

Comment: Good point on the carcinogen thing.  We routinely have this issue with synthetic polymers, and for all intents and purposes, your body is about as well designed to eat alien food as it is too eat plastic.  Just because we're all made of hydrocarbons does not make us biologically compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers describe very well why this may or may not be plausible. However I wanted to bring up the idea of imitation food.

When human cultures interact with each other they sometimes adapt foreign food to their own tastes.

Similarly your alien races can adapt foreign food to their own biology.

With enough research on xenobiology, psychology and a little creativity it would be possible to create a meal that looks similar to the alien dish and presents a similar experience in our own biology. It wouldn't be **exactly** the same, but it would work well enough to fit in during a social event with the aliens so that no one feels left out.

Comment: That's really clever! Especially if the aliens have nanotech or really fancy replicator-esq tech they could tweak stuff like chirality to suit their needs! Great idea!!!